# Load Image at runtime from resource in WPF

Tags: wpf

Im trying to load a image at runtime in WPF using the following code

```
_image = new Image();
BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
src.BeginInit();
src.UriSource = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/images/tagimages/placeholder.png", UriKind.Absolute);                
src.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
src.EndInit();
_image.Source = src;
_image.Stretch = Stretch.None;
```

In my project I have a folder called images and a sub folder of that folder called tagimages that contains the placeholder.png. When I run this code I get the following error

"Cannot locate resource 'images/tagimages/placeholder.png'"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you set the build action of the image files to 'Resource' in your project?

Comment: Yes I have set it to resource and I have made everything lower case to try and eliminate any case issues

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out that I should have used

```
Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/<MyProject>;component/images/tagimages/placeholder.png", UriKind.Absolute);
```

Comment: I am using a simple version of this:

<pre>MainLogoImg.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/<MyProject>;component/Resources/" + CurrentLogo, UriKind.Relative));</code>

Comment: I don't understand how this is an improvement over the old embedded resources where you could just grab the image as a strongly typed property.  What's all that "pack application tripple comma MyProject semi colon relative URL that claims its absolute" stuff?  WPF makes no sense.  It's no wonder people have to go through hours or days of trial and error just to get something simple to work.

Comment: I keep getting path not found and file not found. How do I just see the paths from the programs perspective? I don't want to guess anymore. Just show me the path.

Answer (score 1):

From procedural code you use: @"pack://application:,,,/putyourfilenamehere" for an embedded resource.

Or in other words

BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/myimage.png"));