# Images not getting displayed in Listbox in a user control

Tags: wpf, vb.net, user-controls, listbox

This is my first time using the UserControl in WPF.  Following is my Usercontrol Xaml and background VB Code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="AddNewGenre"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="194" d:DesignWidth="405">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="130" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="72*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="333*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ListBox Name="GenreListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                 Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Value}" Width="128" Height="128" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code file:

```
Public Class AddNewGenre
    Dim Result As HODLib.Classes.GenreClass

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Me.DataContext = Result
    End Sub

    Private Sub UserControl_Loaded(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded

        GenreListBox.ItemsSource = GlobalValues.ImageDictionary
    End Sub

End Class
```

Following is the code that gets the GlobalValues.ImageDictionary:

```
Namespace GlobalValues
    Module CurrentVariables
        Public ImageDictionary As Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary(Of String, BitmapImage)

        Public Sub Initialize()
            ImageDictionary = New Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary(Of String, BitmapImage)

            'try get resources
            GetAllBitmaps()

        End Sub

        Public Sub GetAllBitmaps()
            Try
                ImageDictionary.Clear()
                With ImageDictionary
                    .TryAdd("Box", New BitmapImage(New Uri("Resources\Box.png", UriKind.Relative)))
                    .TryAdd("Tri", New BitmapImage(New Uri("Resources\Tri.png", UriKind.Relative)))
                End With
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End Sub

    End Module
End Namespace
```

The issue is that the images are not getting displayed in the imagelistbox, only a black item is getting displayed.  Could you please tell me what is the wrong thing I did here.

Comment: Forgot to mention, the image files are set to build type of resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a answer from this post: [Accessing Build Action Resource type files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784710/load-image-at-runtime-from-resource-in-wpf) In my case I made value to string of format "/HOD;component/Resources/Box.png" rather than the BitmapImage

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `ItemsSource` from your listbox in xaml since you are already setting it in yur code- behind file.

```
<ListBox Name="GenreListBox"
                 Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
```